# Set default Time value with Combodate

Tags: javascript, jquery, combodate

I'm trying to set default Time value with Combodate.

Here's a bit of code:

```
<input type="text" id="time" data-format="HH:mm" data-template="HH:mm" name="time">
```

Call Combodate:

```
$('#time').combodate({
  minuteStep: 1,
  value:  getCurrentTime(),
});
```

Here getCurrentTime() function:

```
function getCurrentTime(){
  var date = new Date;
  date.setTime(date);

  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var hour = date.getHours();

  return hour + ':' + minutes;
}
```

I've used the same logic for a data field with success, why set the value for time not work?

Comment: have you checked this - http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/

Comment: This method works correctly, I apologize for having opened a useless question

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have an extra comma after getCurrentTime()

---

But [MomentJs](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/) can help you a lot if you are using date and time in your project.

moment().format('hh:mm')

```
$('#time').combodate({
  minuteStep: 1,
  value:  moment().format('hh:mm')
});
```